# Projecting python list onto existing values (with generator of generators)

Tags: python, list

Given a constant, a sorted list of floats and a list of 2-element list of floats,

```
CONST = 1.
lst1 = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1] #sorted
lst2 = [[2.0, 0.9], [3.1, 1.5], [1.0, 3.0], [2.5, 2.0]]
```

I construct a new list with the pairs `[CONST, a]` for all the elements of `lst1`

I need to "project" `list2` on the list of `[CONST,a]`: the second value of the pairs in `lst2` will be changed to the closest value in list1 and the first value of the pair will be the sum of all the first values for a same second value.

So the result with the example given would be:

```
[[6.1, 1.2], [3.5, 2.4], [2.0, 3.1]]
```

So far I have something like:

```
from itertools import groupby
from bisect import bisect
from operator import itemgetter

for t in lst2:
    i = bisect(lst1, t[1])
    bounds = lst1[i-1:i+1] if i else [lst1[0]]
    t[1] = min(bounds, key=lambda x: abs(x-t[1]))

lst2 += [[CONST, a] for a in lst1]
lst2 = sorted(lst2, key=itemgetter(1))
res = [[sum([t[0] for t in group]), keys] for keys, group in groupby(lst2, itemgetter(1))]
```

but the lists (esp. `lst1`) can be long (1e5+) and I have a feeling that I could have better efficiency there. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an intersting way of doing it: a generator of generators ! Python is great ! This is about twice as fast as the previous code.

```
CONST = 1.
lst1 = [1.2, 2.4, 3.1] #sorted
lst2 = [[2.0, 0.9], [3.1, 1.5], [1.0, 3.0], [2.5, 2.0]]

def gen_generator(lst1):
    #Create iterators to form consecutive pairs
    it1_1, it1_2 = iter(lst1), islice(lst1+[float('inf')], 1, None)
    #Create iterator over items to insert and initialize p
    gen_generator.it2 = iter(sorted(lst2, key=itemgetter(1)))
    gen_generator.p=next(gen_generator.it2)
    for t1, t2 in zip(it1_1, it1_2):
        #Calculate the mid point of the pair t1, t2
        sup = (t1+t2)/2 if t2 != float('inf') else float('inf')
        #Create a generator for each item in lst1
        def generator():
            #All the previously inserted items have disappeared
            #So yield any p such that p[1] < sup
            while gen_generator.p is not None and gen_generator.p[1] < sup:
                yield gen_generator.p[0]
                #Move to next or None
                gen_generator.p = next(gen_generator.it2, None)
            #Add the constant
            yield CONST
        yield generator

res = [[sum(gen()), t] for gen, t in zip(gen_generator(lst1), lst1)]
return res
```

Comment: How long will it take you to understand this code when, 2 weeks from now, you'll want to introduce a little modification? Imho, from this point of view your original code, the one in the question, is way better...

Comment: This is what comments are for. I don't mind abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to do faster since the sort dominates the running time, but here's a version that doesn't require to resort lst1. It does however iterate through lst1:

```
sorted_lst2 = sorted(lst2, key=itemgetter(1))
i = 0
res = []
k = 0
while i + 1 < len(lst1):
    before = lst1[i]
    const = CONST
    while i + 1 < len(lst1) and before == lst1[i + 1]:
        const += CONST
        i += 1
    after = lst1[i + 1]
    mid = before + (after - before) / 2
    sum_before = 0
    while k < len(sorted_lst2) and sorted_lst2[k][1] <= mid:
        sum_before += sorted_lst2[k][0]
        k += 1
    res.append([const + sum_before, before])
    i += 1
sum_before = 0
while k < len(sorted_lst2):
    sum_before += sorted_lst2[k][0]
    k += 1
res.append([CONST + sum_before, lst1[-1]])
```